# Extract one column into multiple Column csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-analysis

my credit credit_scoring.csv is like this how can i make it in an organised way  14 column and each column has it's corresponding value

```
Seniority;Home;Time;Age;Marital;Records;Job;Expenses;Income;Assets;Debt;Amount;Price;Status
    0                                         9.0;1.0;60.0;30.0;0.0;1.0;1.0;73.0;129.0;0.0;0...
    1                                         17.0;1.0;60.0;58.0;1.0;1.0;0.0;48.0;131.0;0.0;...
    2                                         10.0;0.0;36.0;46.0;0.0;2.0;1.0;90.0;200.0;3000...
    3                                         0.0;1.0;60.0;24.0;1.0;1.0;0.0;63.0;182.0;2500....
    4                                         0.0;1.0;36.0;26.0;1.0;1.0;0.0;46.0;107.0;0.0;0...
    .                                         .................................................
    .                                         .................................................
    .                                         .................................................
    .                                         .................................................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use read_csv() with `sep=';'`

Your example data isn't great, but I tried to do the most of it.

I saved it as `a.csv` and here is the code:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.read_csv('a.csv', sep=';')
Out[2]:
   Seniority  Home  Time   Age  Marital  Records  Job  Expenses  Income  Assets  Debt  Amount  Price  Status
0        9.0   1.0  60.0  30.0      0.0      1.0  1.0      73.0   129.0     0.0   0.0     NaN    NaN     NaN
1       17.0   1.0  60.0  58.0      1.0      1.0  0.0      48.0   131.0     0.0   NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
2       10.0   0.0  36.0  46.0      0.0      2.0  1.0      90.0   200.0  3000.0   NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
3        0.0   1.0  60.0  24.0      1.0      1.0  0.0      63.0   182.0  2500.0   NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
4        0.0   1.0  36.0  26.0      1.0      1.0  0.0      46.0   107.0     0.0   0.0     NaN    NaN     NaN
```